# SQL - Reassign values depending on a certain condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to reassign a value depending on how many days have elapsed from a certain date until today.
But I get the following error:

> invalid column name.

I do not need to save the value in the table, just see it in the view.

```
SELECT top 100 DATEDIFF(day, DateColumn, getdate()) as antiquity, 
       CASE WHEN antiquity <= 1000 THEN 'do something'
            WHEN antiquity >  1000 THEN 'do something else'
       END
  FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Well the error tells you the problem, one of the colums you are trying to select is not correct.  Confirm that DateColumn and antiquity exist in myTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this. You can't use your alias like that.

```
SELECT top 100 DATEDIFF(day, DateColumn, getdate()) as antiquity, 
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateColumn, getdate()) <= 1000 THEN 'do something'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateColumn, getdate()) > 1000 THEN 'do something else'
END
FROM myTable;
```